# How to sample from a fixed set of observations according to some distribution

Tags: random-variables, normal-distribution

This is not about *generating* random variables from a distribution. Rather let's assume we have a fixed set of observations of some variable, and I want to select a subset of samples from them according to $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ with known $\mu,\sigma$. Are there any deterministic or stochastic methods designed for this? Thanks.

Comment: It seems rather pointless.  If have a fixed set of (assumed independent) observations it doesn't matter how you choose a subset.  The statistical analysis won't depend on how they are selected, only on the number.

Comment: Statistical analysis is another thing. I am only curious about how one can choose a subset that "looks like" the desired distribution.

Comment: My previous note includes your question.  Independence of the observations means it doesn't matter how you choose a subset.  All that matters is size of subset. Larger size leads to better match of the actual distribution.

Comment: Sorry if there is confusion in the way I ask. I understand a larger sample size will better match the actual distribution. But my question does not concern the original distribution. For example, if I already have 10000 i.i.d samples drawn from a uniform distribution among $[-10,10]$, I wonder whether I can select 100 samples from them to make these 100 samples look like they are drawn from $N(0,1)$, even though I know they are not.

Comment: As I have been trying to say, it won't make any difference.  What is confusing to me is what you mean by sampling from a distribution?  What are you doing with a number drawn from the uniform distribution?  Are you doing anything other than generating numbers?